# Using disp function to display values

Tags: matlab, for-loop, xlsread, disp

`Data.xlsx` is an excel file containing the data for **156** students. From cell **4** of the excel file, the **1st** Student Number is displayed and if you increment by **7**, you have the **2nd** Student Number and so on up until the last cell **1094**.

```
F = xlsread('Data.xlsx');

for ii =  4:7:1094
    studentNumbers = disp(F(ii)); 
end
```

but this gives me an error saying "`Too many output arguments`". However if I just specify `disp(F(ii))`, it does not give me any error and displays all the student numbers in order.

Is there a better way to do this so that I can assign all these Student Numbers into an array called `studentNumbers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html) is a function that displays the number on screen, not assigns it to another variable. If you want to assign you just use `=`. So your loop should be:

```
for ii =  4:7:1094
    studentNumbers = F(ii); 
end
```

Now, as @Sardar has pointed correctly, there is no need for a loop here, you can just assign all values in one command, using the vector `4:7:1094` as an indexing. As in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684145/2627163):

```
studentNumbers = F(4:7:1094);
```

But, if you can define the range of the data in Excel, then `xlread` lets you skip this assignment by setting the function to read a specific range, like:

```
sheet = 1; % if the data in in sheet 1
xlRange = 'D:D'; % if all the data is in column D
studentNumbers = xlsread('Data.xlsx',sheet,xlRange)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to do the following:

```
studentNumbers = F(4:7:1094);
```